# problem with reading RGB values of pixels using pyglet

Tags: python, pixel, pyglet

For a programming project, I need to read pixels from a loaded image using pyglet. 
I used "pyglet.image.load('map.png')" to load the image, and I found out that you can retrieve the image data using img.get_image_data().
I use line `mapImage.get_region(x,y,1,1).get_image_data().get_data("RGBA", 4)`

to read the data from the pixel located at (x,y). This is where I get stuck. When I print the result of the line above, I get an empty space. Could anyone clarify how I extract the RGB values from the string returned by the get_data() function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapImage... returns a string with 4 characters representing rgba.

Try this:

```
pix = mapImage.get_region(x,y,1,1).get_image_data().get_data("RGBA", 4)

print 'r = ' + str(ord(pix[0]))
print 'g = ' + str(ord(pix[1]))
print 'b = ' + str(ord(pix[2]))
print 'a = ' + str(ord(pix[3]))
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I wouldn't have figured out that you would need to convert the string from unicode first =)